# Rkhunter show me "warning"

Tags: files, rootkit, rkhunter

Why rkhunter shows me a "warning" in /usr/bin/lwp-request? At the end of the dialog shows: Files properties checks...
              Files checked: 149
              Suspect Files: 1

With ClamAV it shows nothing.

Comment: The file */usr/bin/lwp-request* seems to be a part of [package `libwww-perl`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=lwp-request&mode=exactfilename&suite=bionic&arch=any). So it should be safe.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/373718/rkhunter-gives-me-a-warning-for-usr-bin-lwp-request-what-should-i-do-debi?rq=1 has a well upvoted answer assuming you mean `/usr` and not `/urs` - if it really is the later then it's probably something bad!

Comment: /usr, Sometimes I make mistakes by typing fast :(